# Why does fread read garbage from non-binary files?

Tags: c, file, fread

I know that fread is not meant to be used with non-binary files. However, I was wondering: If I provide the function with the correct size of the input, why shouldn't it return the correct values, but instead it returns garbage?

```
FILE *fp;
int val = 0;

if(fp = fopen("test.txt", "r")){
    fread(&val, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    printf("val read %d \n", val);

    fclose(fp);

}

if(fp = fopen("test.txt", "r")){
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &val);
    printf("val read %d \n", val);

    fclose(fp);

}
```

As an example, if I read a file with inside only 1234567, the output is

```
val read 875770417

val read 1234567
```

Comment: What's the meaning of garbage? Which is the content of the file? Which is the output?

Comment: What file are you reading and what kind of garbage you're getting? Please include the most relevant parts _in the question_ (not in comments).

Comment: Sorry, I made the wrong question. I meant fread and not fscanf. I added an example too.

Answer (score 2):

You are using fscanf with the -d specifier which according to the specification extracts - Any number of decimal digits (0-9), optionally preceded by a sign (+ or -).

The problem is that digits are not stored as strings in binary file but as bytes. To read the data in bytes use fread.  Please see here:
[Using fscanf in binary mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575044/using-fscanf-in-binary-mode)

Comment: Thanks for you reply Dave. I believe I made an error while writing the question, the real one was related to the fread function. I do not understand why it should not work with non-binary files

Comment: @barry91 - NP.  A similar question was asked in the past and should answer your question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326852/c-fread-binary-number-and-convert-it-to-ascii-code

Answer (score 1):

If it says 1234567 in your file as text you can read it with fread as well

but `fread(&val, sizeof(int), 1, fp);` is not correct, it presumes that the integer was written with binary representation i.e. as an `int`, not as text, so instead you need to read it as text:

```
char buf[8];
fread(buf,1, sizeof(buf)-1, fp);
buf[sizeof(buf)-1] = '\0';
```

now you have the string 1234567 in buf

```
puts(buf);
```